# backend design gets collapsed when changed to client side compilation mode

Tags: magento2, compilation

After magento 2 installation, when I change to `client side compilation` mode and save the config the backend design gets collapsed like below,

[image]

What should be done to resolve this issue?

Comment: same happened to me always. change it to `server dude less compilation` will make design  correct.

Comment: But I heard that server side compilation mode is not advicable.

Comment: i am talking about this design problem you get after change leave it as it is. i will not create any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to follow below simple  steps to do working:

First You have to remove `magento2/pub/static/frontend` and `magento2/pub/static/adminhtml` folder.

Set developer mode using command,
php bin/magento `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` mode for deployment.

Remove var folder and check again.

Comment: The backend design is now set. But the frontend styles are not getting applied.

Comment: Have you check inside pub/static/frontend folder contains your theme or not?

Comment: Hi,
  After changing to client side mode, new theme is blank, no product is shown. Do you know why ?